# Spring JPA fetch ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a user with authorities (ManyToMany relationship):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user_authority",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authority_name", referencedColumnName = "name")})
    private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "authority")
public class Authority implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String name;

}
```

Liquibase (without user, he has just an id):

```
<createTable tableName="authority">
        <column name="name" type="varchar(50)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>

    <createTable tableName="user_authority">
        <column name="user_id" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="authority_name" type="varchar(50)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>

    <addPrimaryKey columnNames="user_id, authority_name" tableName="user_authority"/>
    ...
```

I have to fetch all user authorities, that equals some name. For example, I have to fetch all admins (users, that have the authority 'ROLE_ADMIN').

Comment: I think your JPA mapping is wrong. You are using **@ManyToMany** annotation in one of the entities but not in the other.

Comment: This code from JHipster, so I think it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without custom query, this could work:

```
List<Authority> admin_authorities = authorityRepository.findByName("ROLE_ADMIN");
List<User> admins = userRepository.findByAuthoritiesIn(admin_authorities);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search directly by entity instead of name. With `MEMBER OF` you tell to JPA: "Fetch all entities that have X entity instead X collection".

```
@NamedQuery(name="findByAuth",
            query="SELECT u FROM User u WHERE :auth "+
                  "MEMBER OF u.authorities")
public class User implements Serializable {

    /* ... */
}
```

Inside your service:

```
public List<User> getByAuth(Authority auth) {
    TypedQuery<User> query = em.createNamedQuery(
                                    "findByAuth",
                                    User.class);
    query.setParameter("auth", auth);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: I should not user entity manager, so I have tried JpaRepository's query:
`@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE ?1 MEMBER OF u.authorities")`. The result is:
`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [ROLE_ADMIN] did not match expected type [com.test.model.Authority (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [ROLE_ADMIN] did not match expected type [com.test.model.Authority (n/a)]`